# Compiling a C++ program with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gnu

How can I compile a C++ program with the GCC compiler?

#### File *info.c*

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   cout << "C++ compiler in use and version is " << __cplusplus << endl;
   #endif
   cout <<"Version is " << __STDC_VERSION__ << endl;
   cout << "Hi" << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << endl;
}
```

And when I try to compile `info.c`:

`gcc info.C`

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
cout                                /var/tmp/ccPxLN2a.o
endl(ostream &)                     /var/tmp/ccPxLN2a.o
ostream::operator<<(ostream &(*)(ostream &))/var/tmp/ccPxLN2a.o
ostream::operator<<(int)            /var/tmp/ccPxLN2a.o
ostream::operator<<(long)           /var/tmp/ccPxLN2a.o
ostream::operator<<(char const *)   /var/tmp/ccPxLN2a.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Isn't the GCC compiler capable of compiling C++ programs?
On a related note, what is the difference between `gcc` and `g++`?

Comment: Use `gcc` for C code. Use `g++` for C++ code.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

`gcc` can actually compile C++ code just fine. The errors you received are **linker** errors, not compiler errors.

Odds are that if you change the compilation line to be this:

```
gcc info.C -lstdc++
```

which makes it link to the standard C++ library, then it will work just fine.

However, you should just make your life easier and use `g++`.

---

[Rup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243245/rup) says it best in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178342/compiling-a-c-program-with-gcc#comment3304995_3206158) to another answer:

> [...] gcc will
> select the correct back-end compiler
> based on file extension (i.e. will
> compile a .c as C and a .cc as C++)
> and links binaries against just the
> standard C and GCC helper libraries by
> default regardless of input languages;
> g++ will also select the correct
> back-end based on extension except
> that I think it compiles all C source
> as C++ instead (i.e. it compiles both
> .c and .cc as C++) and it includes
> libstdc++ in its link step regardless
> of input languages.

Answer (score 58):

If you give the code a .c extension the compiler thinks it is C code, not C++. And the C++ compiler driver is called g++, if you use the gcc driver you will have linker problems, as the standard C++ libraries will not be linked by default. So you want:

```
g++ myprog.cpp
```

And do not even consider using an uppercase .C extension, unless you never want to port your code, and are prepared to be hated by those you work with.

Comment: @Neil: from what I can tell, gcc does consider a `.C` (capital) extension a c++ extension. The following works just fine: `gcc test.C -lstdc++ -o test` or `g++ test.C -o test`.

Comment: @Evan Yes, of course it does. That does not mean that you should ever use it though, as it will cause terrible portability problems, as do all case-sensitive file names. The extension for C++ files should always be .cpp. This causes no problems, and is guaranteed to work on all common operating systems.

Answer (score 27):

You should use [`g++`](https://www.cprogramming.com/g++.html) instead of `gcc`.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Please give the reason too and the answer is not complete. I don't know is this the standard answer look like ?

Answer (score 16):

By default, `gcc` selects the language based on the file extension, but you can force `gcc` to select a different language backend with the *-x* option thus:

```
gcc -x c++
```

More options are detailed on the `gcc` man page under "Options controlling the kind of output". See e.g. *[gcc(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)* (search on the page for the text `-x language`).

This facility is very useful in cases where `gcc` can't guess the language using a file extension, for example if you're generating code and feeding it to `gcc` via [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)).

Answer (score 13):

The difference between `gcc` and `g++` are:

```
     gcc            |        g++
compiles C source   |   compiles C++ source
```

Use `g++` instead of `gcc` to compile you C++ source.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that, as in the other answers here. gcc will select the correct back-end compiler based on file extension (i.e. will compile a .c as C and a .cc as C++) and links binaries against just the standard C and GCC helper libraries by default regardless of input languages; g++ will also select the correct back-end based on extension except that I think it compiles all C source as C++ instead (i.e. it compiles both .c and .cc as C++) and it includes libstdc++ in its link step regardless of input languages.

Comment: @Rup: correct, this is basically what I was saying in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, gcc determines the filetype from the suffix.  So, make it foo.cc and it should work.

And, to answer your other question, *that* is the difference between "gcc" and "g++". gcc is a frontend that chooses the correct compiler.

Answer (score 2):

An update with my *GCC version 10.3.0* on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29). Even if I add `-lstdc++` or use the correct extension, `cc1plus` must be installed on the system. Otherwise this error shows up:

> gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: No such file or directory

One way to get this is to install `g++` even if you're not going to use it directly, e.g. `sudo apt install g++`.

Now, if I use the extension `.cc`, I can just call `gcc` directly, however, warnings and errors still show up. To use `gcc` cleanly, with a `.c` extension I have to call it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36191856/5362795):

```
gcc -x c++ info.c -lstdc++
```

Shorter if I use the `.cc` extension, like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3206195/5362795):

```
gcc info.cc -lstdc++
```

Or like others have said, just use `g++ info.c` instead. No extra parameters are needed to indicate C++, and it works with `.c`, `.cc` and `.cpp` extensions.

Answer (score 1):

For a .cpp File:

```
g++ myprog.cpp -o myprog
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked well for me. Just one line code on the Windows command line ([CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)).

First, confirm that you have installed `gcc` (for C) or g++ (for C++) compiler.

On the command line, for gcc, type:

```
gcc --version
```

On the command line, for g++, type:

```
g++ --version
```

If it is installed then proceed.

Now, compile your .c or .cpp using the command line.

For C syntax:

```
gcc -o exe_filename yourfilename.c
```

Example:

```
gcc -o myfile myfile.c
```

Here **exe_filename (myfile in example)** is the name of **your .exe file** which you want to produce after compilation (Note: I have not put any extension here). And **yourfilename.c (myfile.c in example)** is the **your source file** which has the .c extension.

Now go to the folder containing your .c file. Here you will find a file with the .exe extension. Just open it. Hurray...

For C++ syntax:

```
g++ -o exe_filename yourfilename.cpp
```

After it, the process is the same as for the C syntax.

Comment: The question was "How to compile a C++ program with gcc compiler?" not "How to compile a C program with gcc compiler? or How to compile a C++ program with g++ compiler?"

Comment: Nice catch! @DevX