# Template function for full specialization

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, template-instantiation

I have a function template declared in an header file. This function is an archiver which is supposed to support several other types (classes) implemented through the project. The idea is to have a base template declaration which each class then specialises to its own types.

```
// Archiver.h
template <class T> void archive(Archiver & archiver, const T & obj);
```

This method does not have an implementation. Now I create a class (say, `Header`) and I want it to be archivable. As such, it is my intent to specialise the method. Here's what I have now:

```
// Header.h
extern template void archive(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj);
```

I declare the function as `extern` because I implement it in the .cpp file

```
// Header.cpp
template <> void archive(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj)
{
 // Code here
}
```

This gives `specialization after instantiation`. I've tried other combinations as well:

1. Implementing directly in the header file, as is usually recommended for templates: I get "multiple definition"
2. Implementation in the .cpp file without a declaration on the header: I get `undefined reference` when calling the method from another compilation unit

So what is the correct of implementing this?

Edit:

Initially I decided to go with templates because of the inverse process, unarchiving. Basically I could write `unarchive<Header>()` instead of `unarchive_header()` which seemed more appropriate.

I believe I should also mention that I'm compiling this using Android Studio and the Gradle build system, which is why I'm using gcc and not g++. I also gave gcc the following compiler flags:

```
-std=gnu++11 -fexceptions -fpermissive -lstdc++
```

`-fpermissive` was an act of despair.

Comment: Why not use separate functions?

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to make archive a separate function, I'd recommend doing it other way round: using a virtual method of a class you want to achieve (and an ABC/Interface for all classes that can be achieved). That's what I'd use.

Answer (score 5):

Just don't use templates:

```
// Header.h
void archive(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj);
```

and

```
// Header.cpp
void archive(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj)
{
 // Code here
}
```

Much simpler that way. Simply make an unqualified call to `archive()` and make sure this overload is declared in the same namespace as `Header`  and let ADL do its magic.

Comment: I believe at the time I decided to go with templates because of the inverse process, unarchiving. I could write `unarchive<Header>()`, instead of `unarchive_header()`. I think the first form is more convenient

Comment: @AndréFratelli Why do you think you have to write `unarchive_header()`? Just write `unarchive()`.

Comment: Because `Header` is not the only unarchivable class and this function wouldn't be overridable because it does not get any parameters

Answer (score 2):

**Why use a function template?**

You said:

> The idea is to have a base template declaration which each class then specialises to its own types.

If a function template does not have a default implementation, it is pointless to have one at all. You can just use:

```
extern void archive(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj);
```

when you need it.

**If you must use a function template**

The line

```
extern template void archive(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj);
```

is not right. It needs to be:

```
template <> void archive<Header>(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj);
```

The implementation needs to use the same signature.

```
template <> void archive<Header>(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj)
{
}
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

I tried the following to simulate your situation.

socc.h:

```
#pragma once

struct Archiver {};

template <class T> void archive(Archiver & archiver, const T & obj);

struct Header {};

template <> void archive<Header>(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj);
```

socc.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "socc.h"

int main()
{
   Archiver ar;
   Header obj;
   archive(ar, obj);
}
```

socc-2.cc:

```
#include "socc.h"

template <> void archive<Header>(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj)
{
}
```

Command to build:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall    socc.cc  socc-2.cc -o socc
```

The program was built successfully.

Comment: That second approach gives "undefined reference" at the calling point. I'm still looking into not using templates.

Comment: @AndréFratelli, See Update.

Comment: Could you make it work with gcc instead? I've tried adding the `-lstdc++` compiler flag. I didn't mention it initially (it didn't seem relevant) but I'm using Gradle to build for Android. I'm also looking into how to switch to g++ with gradle

Comment: @AndréFratelli, It doesn't make sense to compile C++ code with `gcc`. You should figure out how to use `g++ `in your development tool. I am not familiar with it.

Comment: I know, but then I saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3206195/2328352). I'm already looking into how to use g++

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think, overloading simply does the trick. You don't really need templates here.

```
void archive(Archiver & archiver, const Header & obj);
void archive(Archiver & archiver, const Footer & obj);
void archive(Archiver & archiver, const Whatever & obj);
```