# having trouble getting started with ISOCPP.net C++ build for windows (nuwen)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw

I have a minimal MinGW (nuwen) set up from [isocpp.org 'Get started'](https://isocpp.org/get-started) which is gcc version 6.1.0  compiled for windows

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf ("hello world\n");

    std::string mystring {"my string"};

}
```

I keep getting the following error (among others)

> C:\util\MinGW\proj>gcc main.cpp
>
> C:\Users\gmyer\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXSjGdh.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `std::allocator::allocator()'    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What I have done

- checked that string file exists in include directory
  CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\util\MinGW\include;C:\util\MinGW\include\freetype2
  C_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\util\MinGW\include;C:\util\MinGW\include\freetype2
- checked that allocator exists in the 'string' file

Do I need to add another include file to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compile the code with `g++` (see [Compiling a C++ program with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3178342/3235496)).

Also use the `--std=c++11` switch (`g++ --std=c++11`) or change

```
std::string mystring {"my string"};
```

into

```
std::string mystring = "my string";
```

([uniform initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) is a C++11 feature and [Nuwen MinGW Distro](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) v 14.0 uses C++03 as default mode).