# can't understand "std::cout"

Tags: c++, std, iostream, cout

The back story: I am trying to create an account on en.cppreference.com.
part of the process involves: 
What is displayed by std::cout << "ev" << 'a';

The dilemma: I have no idea what the hell that is.
I tried putting that into the terminal, but got nothing useful.
I tried putting that in code and compiling it ... still no luck.
I googled it, but got no closer to understanding what the hell they are asking me to do.
and last but not least, I went to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout

and found the following code, which I also tried to compile without luck.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {
    int n;
    Foo() {
       std::cout << "static constructor\n";
    }
    ~Foo() {
       std::cout << "static destructor\n";
    }
};
Foo f; // static object
int main()
{
    std::cout << "main function\n";
}
```

attempts to compile it resulted in:

```
[bad_cat@KittyLitter LearningCode]$ gcc input.c
input.c:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

All I'm trying to do is get past this, so I can create an account and learn about C programming.

Comment: You use a C compiler (`gcc`) to compile code written in C++. You must use a C++ compiler, such as `g++`.

Comment: You don't need a cppreference.com account to learn C. Everything on cppreference.com is available to you without logging in. Having an account only allows you to edit the wikis.

Comment: @DYZ, thanks, that's good to know. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code presented by you in a C++ program. You need to save it in `file.cpp` format, after that you need to compile with `g++ file.cpp` and it should work.

You have saved it `file.c` format and compiling it with `gcc`, which is C standard, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

This is a C++ program and you are trying to compile using `gcc` compiler. Use `g++` compiler to compile this program.

Comment: I was under the impression that gcc was c/c++ so I had attempted to compile as .c and .cpp thinking that I had covered that. But I just tried g++ input.cpp and that worked fine. Sorry but I am no longer able to mark your answer as correct, because my rep dropped from 16 to 10 as soon as I asked this question.

Comment: @Vasqi, that is okay. Note that `<iostream>` is a C++ library. Glad to help.

Comment: `gcc` is C/C++. You need to link the standard C++ libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The `gcc` compiler is capable of compiling C++ code, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178342/compiling-a-c-program-with-gcc). I think the problem is, that you compile with `gcc input.c`. Try changing the filename into `input.cpp`, as `*.c` files are C files and `*.cpp` files are C++ files. You also need to tell a linker, as the C++ are not linked by standard. So this should work: `gcc input.cpp -lstdc++`. You can also use the `g++` compiler, where the libraries are linked by default.
To answer the other part of your question: `std::cout` is in fact `std::` and `cout`. `std` ist just the console (in C it is stdout, I'm not sure if it is called the same in C++). And `cout` prints out text.

Comment: Xeneda, I did make a failed attempt to compile as: gcc input.cpp before I came here to seek advice.

Comment: Try compiling with gcc input.cpp -lstdc++. This will link the standard C++ libraries.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout` prints given string in console. I recommend try some basic tutorial of C++, maybe [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/learning-c-cplusplus-step-by-step) will be fine.

Two simpliest examples which should work:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

And second (doing exactly the same):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
}
```