# Linux GCC Link Error on Simple Derived Classes

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I see people asking questions similar to this but not quite and always with code more complicated than mine.  I have reduced my problem to the simplest possible terms:

Using Linux GCC compiler, this will build fine:

```
class MyBase
{
    void Clear() {}
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase
{
    void Clear() {}
};
```

This will not:

```
class MyBase
{
    virtual void Clear() {}
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase
{
    void Clear() {}
};
```

The link stage produces the following error:

```
/tmp/ccmEFi6P.o:(.rodata._ZTI9MyDerived[_ZTI9MyDerived]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/tmp/ccmEFi6P.o:(.rodata._ZTI6MyBase[_ZTI6MyBase]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Sorry, I am just getting used to the formatting system here.

OK, the compiler I am using is gcc and when I enter "gcc --version" I get:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

The problem popped up while working with a much larger set of source files but I always like to try and reduce the code to the smallest bit as possible that still reproduces the problem. I have done this with a single source file:

**derive.cpp:**

```
class MyBase
{
    virtual void Clear() {}
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase
{
    void Clear() {}
};

int main()
{
    MyDerived md;
    return 0;
}
```

That is literaly all there is. It will build if I remove the "virtual" specifier from the base class' declaration of "Clear()". It will not build if I put it back. In both cases, my command line is:

```
gcc - o derive derive.cpp
```

and the full text of the build output is:

```
/tmp/cckxCssh.o:(.rodata._ZTI9MyDerived[_ZTI9MyDerived]+0x0): undefined 
reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/tmp/cckxCssh.o:(.rodata._ZTI6MyBase[_ZTI6MyBase]+0x0): undefined reference 
to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more on asking questions that will attract quality answers.  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43665957/edit) to include a bit more information?  What GCC and libc versions; what `uname`; what compiler command line?  Also, please add the rest of the source you are trying to compile and link.  Is everything in one file, or are `MyBase` and `MyDerived` in separate files?  Thanks!

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+undefined+reference+to+vtable+for+__cxxabiv1%3A%3A__class_type_info

Comment: The common theme seems to be that this is related to use of RTTI and/or linking C++ with C code.

Comment: Did you literally use "gcc - o derive derive.cpp"? Did you try removing the space between '-' and 'o'?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `gcc` to compile C++ code, which is a bad idea (as explained, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178342/compiling-a-c-program-with-gcc)). Your code compiles and links fine using

```
g++ -o derive derive.cpp
```

Comment: gcc - o derive derive.cpp

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that was the probem.

Comment: gcc will recognize .cpp files as C++ and compile/link them accordingly. The likely problem is the typo in your command line. You have an extra space between '-' and 'o'.

Comment: @George Did you try to compile the provided code or look at the related question I linked? The error does not come from the extra space in the compilation command. gcc will indeed compile C++ code, but it will not choose the correct backend which leads to the error at the linking stage. In particular, it will not link to libstdc++. You can fix this by using `gcc -o derive derive.cpp  -lstdc++`, or simply use `g++` instead.