# GCC/G++ warnings when using CPLEX 12.8

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang++, cplex

I use CPLEX 12.8 and c++ to code a benders decomposition algorithm. When I use clang++ compiler there is no error. However, when I use g++ the following error occurs:

> In file included from
>   /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/include/ilcplex/ilocplexi.h:1053:0,
>                    from /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/include/ilcplex/ilocplex.h:29,
>   from PARAM.h:12,
>                    from MAIN.cpp:1: /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/include/ilcplex/iloparam.h:83:12:
>   warning: ‘IloCplex::Param::MIP::Limits::SubMIPNodeLim’ is deprecated
>   [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>        struct Limits {            ^ /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/include/ilcplex/iloparam.h:103:40:
>   note: declared here
>          static const IloCplex::LongParam SubMIPNodeLim = LongParam(CPX_PARAM_SUBM

I do not use `SubMIPNodeLim` in my code, so I don't understand why I am receiving this warning. Although g++ produces this kind of warning, it also compiles the code and I can see the results. However, when I use gcc it does not show any results and terminates with a long list of errors. Could you please let me know what is wrong here?

Comment: What you have is not an error, but a *warning*. And you might be using some functionality which in turn uses the deprecated function.

Comment: @MikeKinghan The only difference between the `gcc` and `g++` programs are the default directories added to the include and library search paths and that `gcc` doesn't link with the C++ library. Otherwise both executes the same "backend" programs. Same with `clang` versus `clang++`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know. As I read it, I think this is actually a separate question and that he/she's referring to
undefined reference linkage errors.

Comment: @MikeKinghan: There is not even one single mention of undefined references in the question. You're off base.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed not. I think the OP is not well distinguishing the issue with g++ build
from the issue with gcc build and has provided no diagnostics for the latter.
Have no desire to argue the toss however. Comment deleted.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. I can't find where in the code I have used such a functionality. Is there any way to detect that? Regarding the difference between compilers, now I somehow understand why gcc does not compile my C++ code properly. Comparing g++ and clang++, maybe clang++ can realize that I have not used the deprecated methods in my code (but g++ can't). Is that possible?

Comment: @MikeKinghan: There is no g++/gcc issue. You invented it in your head :) GCC is the name of the whole project/toolchain; don't confuse it with the `gcc` wrapper binary

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is what I mean by the g++/gcc issue: "Although g++ produces this kind of warning, it also compiles the code and I can see the results. However, when I use gcc it does not show any results and terminates with a long list of errors"
The issue is tagged gcc, g++, clang++ and draws a distinction about each. OP subsequently comments
"now I somehow understand why gcc does not compile my C++ code properly. Comparing g++ and clang++ ..."

Comment: @MikeKinghan: Er, okay, so what's happened here is that I appear to have had a stroke or something and didn't see that paragraph at all despite repeated re-reads. Sorry 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter warning is only meant to be informative; the parameter in question is defined in the `ilcplex/iloparam.h` header file (which is included indirectly via `ilcplex/ilocplex.h`), so you'll see that warning even if you aren't using it directly. You can read more information about the deprecated parameter in the 12.8 release notes [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes128/deprecated.html). If you want, you can use the `-Wno-deprecated` compiler option to silence the warning (i.e., see the documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)).

You *can* use gcc to compile C++ code, but you are likely getting a linker error (e.g., see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178342/compiling-a-c-program-with-gcc) stackoverflow thread). However, using `g++` should make your life easier.