# Compiling hello world.cpp in terminal (macOS)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++

I'm trying to compile a C++ helloWorld in terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

I cd to the directory containing the code. I manage to compile with the command g++ -o hello c_helloworld.cpp. But when I use the command gcc -o hello c_helloworld.cpp I get the following error.

> > Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced
> >     from:
> >           std::__1::ctype const& std::__1::use_facet >(std::__1::locale const&)
> >     in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const",
> >     referenced from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ios >::widen(char) const in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::basic_string,
> >     std::__1::allocator >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced
> >     from:
> >           std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in
> >     c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator
> >     ::~basic_string()", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator > std::__1::__pad_and_output >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in
> >     c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::basic_ostream >::put(char)", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ostream >& std::__1::endl
> >     (std::__1::basic_ostream >&) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::basic_ostream >::flush()", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ostream >& std::__1::endl
> >     (std::__1::basic_ostream >&) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::basic_ostream
> >     ::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream >&)", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ostream >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence
> >     (std::__1::basic_ostream >&, char const*, unsigned long) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o
> >     "std::__1::basic_ostream
> >     ::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ostream >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence
> >     (std::__1::basic_ostream >&, char const*, unsigned long) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::cout",
> >     referenced from:
> >           _main in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::ctype::id", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::ctype const& std::__1::use_facet >(std::__1::locale const&)
> >     in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced
> >     from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ios >::widen(char) const in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced
> >     from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ostream >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence
> >     (std::__1::basic_ostream >&, char const*, unsigned long) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o
> >     "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "std::terminate()", referenced from:
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ostream >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence
> >     (std::__1::basic_ostream >&, char const*, unsigned long) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o   "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream >&) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o
> >     "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ostream >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence
> >     (std::__1::basic_ostream >&, char const*, unsigned long) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o
> >     "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
> >           std::__1::basic_ostream >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence
> >     (std::__1::basic_ostream >&, char const*, unsigned long) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o
> >           std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator > std::__1::__pad_and_output >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in
> >     c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o
> >           std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream >&) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o
> >           std::__1::basic_ios >::widen(char) const in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o
> >           Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in c_helloworld-a3d3b8.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> >     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> >     invocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc is used to compile C programs (by default), g++ is for C++. 
So, the behaviour is expected.

By default, gcc links to the standard C library.
If you want to compile C++ programs you can link to the standard C++ library by adding the following option:

```
gcc -o hello c_helloworld.cpp -lstdc++
```

PS. I suggest you to search the website before asking a question, there was already an answer for this.

[Compiling a C++ program with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178342/compiling-a-c-program-with-gcc)

Answer (score 1):

Using g++ is easier for compiling .cpp files. Execute the compiled code by running `./outputfile` in the directory. So basically that would be running

```sh
g++ file.cpp -o file && ./file
```

in the command line

Edit: My mistake.. `gcc` can be used here as well, but it's simpler to just use g++

Comment: g++ is the better solution.  But your last statement is wrong.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178342/compiling-a-c-program-with-gcc

Comment: @2785528 Noted thanks!